# Perform Segue to another storyboard swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, storyboard-reference

Hey I am performing a basic segue from a ViewController in one storyboard to another ViewController second storyboard.

1st storyboard : Main

2nd Storyboard : Settings

I have a reference to `settings.storyboard` in `Main.storyboard`. below are the screen shot of my setup

Storyboard Ref to Settings in Main

[image]

My segue(attributes) to storyboard ref. I am using a custom segue, that slides from right to left :

[image]

Destination VC in settings storyboard.

[image]

My source VC is a navigation embedded-TableViewController, I perform following operation to segue there:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editprofile") as? EditProfile
performSegue(withIdentifier: "settings", sender: nil)
```

With the above setting I am still unable to segue to my Destination VC. I have serach stackoverflow alot and even implemented exactly, but am out of Luck. I just dont know where exactly I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: from screenshot it looks like destination storyboard identifier is - : setEdit.

Comment: Yes! `setEdit` is the Storyboard ID

Comment: you have given class name as identifier not storyboard identifier(setEdit) . And if you also want navigation bar on second controller as well, then perform a push.

Comment: How can I perfrom custom segue and have a nav bar in the other VC. Even If I add navController to destination VC, I might as well need more working, right?

Comment: you have to connect your source controller with navigation controller and not destination controller.

Comment: so i should be doing `navigationController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`. Is this what you are implying?

Comment: you need to push -: navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,
 animated: true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (withIdentifier: "editprofile") portion of your code seems wrong.

In the images you showed, nothing has the identifier of "editprofile". I would change that to "Settings", as it seems like that is your segue's identifier.

Comment: my bad! Stupid mistake. I just overlooked this. Thats what this platform is for. Helping us. Cheers anyway!

Comment: Isnt there a way to perform a custom segue here.

Comment: @AakashDave you may want to create a new question. Include some screenshots of what you are getting vs. what you are hoping to achieve. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

your storyboard id is case sensitive, make sure whatever you typed in your interface builder as your storyboard id is the same and has the same casing as what you have programmatically typed in your swift file